# jQuery .post callback includes the .php- file where the jQuery is called from

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, callback, .post

I have a hello.php file that has some basic html in it. I am using ajax to retrieve data from another.php file. jQuery script posts data to another.php and put the callback data to div.

The problem is that the callback data from .post contains everything in the hello.php plus the actual callback data (check below). I've shortened the files (containing DB-connections for instance) from the actual ones, but the effect is the same whether I use the actual ones or these stubs. This was working just fine before, but was broken when I created a login action to the site. Only includes are objects of different classes that dont work with the posting and there is no reference to include the hello.php file.

Has anyone encounter a problem similar to this?

**hello.php**

```
<html>
    <head>scripts etc..</head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <button id="dataButton" value="GetData">Get Data</button>
        <div id="cb">Callback data here</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**another.php**

```
<?php 
    echo "world!";
?>
```

**jQuery script**

```
<script>
function getWorld() {
    $.post("another.php", function(data) {
        $("#cb").html(data);

        // alert(data); this also contains all of the data in This page 

    });
}
</script>
```

**js function**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dataButton").click(function() {
        getWorld();
    });
});
</script>
```

This will output the following html page source:

```
<html>
    <head>scripts etc..</head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <button id="dataButton" value="GetData">Get Data</button>
        <div id="cb">
<html>
    <head>scripts etc..</head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <button id="dataButton" value="GetData">Get Data</button>
        <div id="cb">Callback data here</div>
    </body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dataButton").click(function() {
        getWorld();
    });
});
</script>

<script>
function getWorld() {
    $.post("another.php", function(data) {
        $("#cb").html(data);

        // alert(data); this also contains all of the data in This page 

    });
}
</script>
```

**`world!`**  // <-- This gets back from server.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dataButton").click(function() {
        getWorld();
    });
});
</script>

<script>
function getWorld() {
    $.post("another.php", function(data) {
        $("#cb").html(data);

        // alert(data); this also contains all of the data in This page 

    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: question is not clear.

Comment: What is the content of another.php? Do you have anything after echo part?

Comment: dfsq:
another.php
There is nothing after the echo part.

`<?php 
    echo "world!";
?>`

DevZer0:
The question is why it behavioring like that? Why does the callback data include all contents of the hello.php.

Comment: Are you putting your `<script>` tags inside your HTML tags? It looks like the tags are outside the HTML body. I've never seen anyone do that before so just wondering if that is the source of the problem.

Comment: The problem was with includes and ralative pathnames. I have one include which has a another include with badly formed relative file path. This included file has the same name as ("hello.php") which, in runtime, resolved to this hello.php containing the html tags. 

Something like this:

`page/view/hello.php`

`include_once "../../entity/hello.php"`

`/page/view/another.php`

`/entity/hello.php`